# IIS URL Rewrite impact on existing hosted applications

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

if we add the URL rewrite now on production server iis then will it affect the existing hosted/deployed application?

Means by adding the URL rewrite will my already hosted applications work properly or do i need to do some changes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where do you set rewrite rules.

If you set at server level, it will affect all sites on IIS.

[image]

If you set it at site level, it will only affect this site. Other sites won't be affected.
[image]